# Making map use set of coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geojson, google-maps-api

I have made a custom google map with the google map api which has a few functions that work well within it - one specifically is limiting the user on what they can view within the bounds of the map.

The map is a very simple 2 sides the front and back of the human body.

What I want to do is add on specific zones in my body, I've read that I can do with via geojason and have been pointed towards qgis to generate my GeoJSON data.

Now with is where I fall down I can make the zones and even the export just the coordinates don't match up. How do I make the coordinates match?

I know to use EPSG:4269, but the coordinates still don't match.

How do I make it match i.e. set a specific long/lat that my map is using?

Comment: Just doublechecking, but you do realize that Google Maps is a Mercator projection, not an equiangular one, right?

Comment: Your speaking in a language that I don't understand.
Sorry - have I used the wrong program?
Moving forward I'm ripping some javascript out a little program that makes geojson code and adding it to my map.

Answer (score 1):

In the end that's what I did - ripped some code out. Got the coordinates that I needed and then had to play around with the json job done.

I got the javascript from here.
http://blog.sallarp.com/geojson-google-maps-editor.html

Comment: ust started doing this and it works, just would be nice to use some graphical package that would mean I can copy and paste get nice smooth lines etc